# cocos2d. Correct blending?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, blend, blending, glblendfunc

I modified standard example "Hello World":

```
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Untitled-1.png"];
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2);
        [label setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_ALPHA}];
        [label setColor:ccBLACK];
        [sprite addChild:label];
        [self addChild:sprite];
```

I got:

[image](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=0de5d100aafc6588c1cbba637193c459)
[image]

How to delete/cut a background around "Hello World" label?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? with {GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_ALPHA} you multiply background color by source alpha and don't draw source color at all, which results in black color where source alpha was 0 and background color where source was opaque.

Comment: I want to get a gradient font and I can't allow myself to buy something like glyph Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my current solution is to init CCLabelTTF something like this:

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64 dimensions:size hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter vAlignment:kCCVerticalTextAlignmentCenter];
```

where size is [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize for my examle.

any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: this solution works perfect for 2 layers only, but erases the third and other layers. It means that area around the label is black, not transparent